# OpenGL ES 2.0 texture is transparent, but does not show OpenGL content behind

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios4, opengl-es-2.0

Using **OpenGL ES 2.0** on **iOS 4**.

I have an **OpenGL** view that inherits from **UIView**. It is in front of a **UIImageView** that provides a background.

I have a .**png** image with transparency that I am using for an **OpenGL** texture.

The problem I am having is the transparency of the image in the **OpenGL** view shows through to the image in the **UIImageView** background. I would like to show content in the **OpenGL** view that is behind the elements with the transparent texture.

The underneath **OpenGL** texture is being rendered, but any portion that has the transparent texture on top does not show the underneath **OpenGL** texture. It shows the **UIImageView** background.

What do I need to do so that the transparency will show content in the **OpenGL** view that is behind the transparent content?

**EDIT**:

I restructured the index array so all elements with transparent textures come at the end and should be rendered after all opaque elements when I call **glDrawElements**.

Still having the problem with the transparency.

I set up some data so that I have 4 vertices and 6 indices for 2 triangles to draw a square with the opaque texture.
There are also 4 vertices and 6 indices for 2 triangles to draw a square with the transparent texture which come after the other entries in the vertex/index arrays. The transparent element coordinates render it in front of the opaque element.

I can see the transparent element, and I can also see the edges of the opaque element sticking out from behind.
However, instead of showing the opaque element which lies immediately behind the transparent element, the transparency goes right through and shows the background of the view behind the OpenGL view.

Opaque yellow square:

[image: Opaque yellow square]

Transparent test image:

[image: Transparent test image]

The transparent image covers the opaque image but the transparency shows the background not the opaque image behind:

[image][image]

Comment: Sounds like you are not necessarily drawing in the proper order. You need to draw all of the content in the OpenGL view behind the transparent .png **before** you draw the transparent .png. Did you do this? An image might be easier to understand as well if you want to post one.

Comment: I made changes to draw all of the opaque elements before any transparent elements, which should all display over opaque elements. Also posted some images to better illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try using some blending? Something like this:

```
//draw your background scene here
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//draw your foreground scene here
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

-----------------EDIT on comment----------------

So you want to do the blending in fragment shader:

```
vec4 color1 = texture2D(backgroundTexture, ...);
vec4 color2 = colorYouGetFromSecondaryTextureOrSomeOtherElement;

vec4 outputColor = color1*(1.0-color2.a) + color2*(color2.a);
outputColor.a = 1.0; //or some function of color1.a and color2.a

gl_FragColor = outputColor;
```

-----------------EDIT 2-------------------------

Also considering your results I would say that you forgot something in your pipeline. You probably use 2 or more textures but only your second is binded resulting in the fragment snippet I posted to be all black but your foreground.. Are you using "active texture"? Something like this:

```
- (void)bindFirstTexture {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, firstTextureID);
}
- (void)bindSecondTexture {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, secondTextureID);
}
```

You need such binding in both, before creating and before drawing multiple textures.

Comment: Not sure how I would do that. All the rendering is done in a single call to glDrawElements(). The textures are determined in the fragment shader.

Comment: I use 6 different textures that all display fine. I then added the transparent texture and they all still render fine, except the transparency displays the view behind, not the texture behind.

So I need to combine the opaque and transparent textures in the shader and output a single element, instead of outputting an opaque and a transparent texture separately? I'll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: I actually implemented your first option with glBlendFunc and it works great. I was able to reorder my indices array so that the transparent and opaque elements were grouped together so I could specify ranges for each in separate glDrawElements calls. Seemed a simpler solution than the fragment shader and works fine so far. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I had a related problem and the blend mode (together with the same question) helped me a lot. Thanks!